# Установленное приложение не появляется в меню

Tags: java, android, отладка, apk

С помощью Android Studio  сделал apk, скинул на телефон. Приложение установилось, но в меню не отображается и следовательно запустить его на телефоне не могу. В настройках оно есть и "установка из внешних источников" включена. При отладке и подключении к компьютеру приложение запускается нормально. В эмуляторе genymotion тоже работает. Минимально необходимая версия для запуска 6,0, в  genymotion и на телефоне 9,0

---

С манифестом все было в порядке. Проблема решилась переносом кода в новый проект.

Comment: В манифесте прописан `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>` для стартовой активити?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 1):

У вас в проекте вашего приложения есть папка `AndroidManifest` и там есть файл `AndroidManifest.xml`. Как уже говорил [@DrawnRaccoon](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/276430/drawn-raccoon) у вас в манифесте должно быть прописано какая именно активность будет стартовой. Это означает что при нажатии на иконку в меню приложений, вы будете переходить на данную активность. Вот что должно быть в активности которую вы хотите сделать стартовой:

```
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Вот так выглядит часть манифеста в целом:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_name">
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Обратимся к [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent?hl=ru#intent-resolution):

> стандартное действие MAIN является главной точкой входа (не требующей
>   никакой другой информации в намерении), а категория LAUNCHER говорит,
>   что эта точка входа должна быть указана в панели запуска приложения.