# Запускается не та страница в

Tags: java, android, xml

Всем привет.
Сейчас хотел создать вторую страницу-Activity. Layout есть, класс есть... Есть функция, которая должна отсылать с первой страницы на вторую. Но при запуске эмулятора запускается ВТОРАЯ страница. В чем дело?

Это MainActivity

```
public void sendpage (View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SendActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Это activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
        android:text="@string/send"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:onClick="sendpage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: `android-studio` здесь ни при чем

Comment: покажите файл AndroidManufest пожалуйста

Comment: Дело либо в манифесте (вторая активность прописана как точка входа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1097968/11515), либо в настройке запуска в студии (указана не дефолтная активность), либо функция запуска второй активности вызывается сразу при старте первой.

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на файл `AndroidManifest.xml`, который находится по пути **app>manifests**.

[image: AndroidManifest.xml]

Откройте его и далее найдите в нем тег `<activity>`, в котором будет указано `android:name=".MainActivity"`, и обратите внимание на тег внутри него: `<intent-filter>`. В нем должны быть прописаны следующие строки:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Если данные строки присутствуют и с файлом манифеста все в порядке, но проблема не решилась, то следует выполнить следующие действия:

1. Если вы используете Android Studio, то перейдите через панель навигации в: **Run > Edit Configurations > слева выберите Android App->app > справа Launch Options > Launch**;
2. Выберите из выпадающего списка **Specified Activity**;
3. Ниже в поле **Activity** укажите нужную активити для запуска.

[image: Edit Configurations]